# Final Cut Pro 10.0.7 Yosemite Compatibility?

Tags: macos, final-cut-pro

How do I get Final Cut Pro to work on Yosemite?

Any fixes will be greatly appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final Cut Pro (10.0.7) is incompatible with Yosemite. When I was updating my mac to Yosemite, I had to update many apps so they would work including Final Cut Pro.